# How can i select Datakey value of a grid

Tags: asp.net

How can i select Datakey value of a grid .? I tried but only getting inside  selected index changed event.
[In my application there is a grid.In that grid there link buttons.My issue is when i am clicking on link button i want to acceess value in Datakeynames.  is there any method to access value in Datakeynames. or is there any other property for grid to keep key values ].Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have your answer at below link

[How to get the Command Argument on Row Data bound Event of gridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213492/how-to-get-the-command-argument-on-row-data-bound-event-of-gridview)

Happy coding!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,
Assign your Value in the Command Argument.
In RowCommand Event,

```
    if (e.CommandName == "Link")
    {            
        string Value = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
    }
```